# IntelliJ IDEA creates OUT folder in the Project, makes Problems

Tags: intellij-idea

When I first ran the code, a new folder showed up named `out` which I didn't pay attention to in the start,
when I changed the code in the same file, the file was displaying the code written by me afterwards, but the output was always what the first (non-changed) file gave.

The file's code was new, but the output was the earlier one.

Whenever I delete the `out` folder, then if I run it, it repeats by displaying the desired result once, then displaying it again and again

The `out` is created every time I delete it. If I try to edit the Main.class file in `out`, it doesn't, notifying me that it is read only

`This is the image when I had already ran it and deleted the 'out' folder:https://www.mediafire.com/file/5e08wscgtxl9q5g/wr.png/file`

`This is the image in which it has been created again and gave the Right result once:https://www.mediafire.com/file/rrokrpu27dr9eiq/ro.png/file`

This goes on in a loop.

Please help in a way that I as newbie at Java am able to understand.

Comment: `out` folder is for compiled sources. Each time you execute the code, compiled files change if corresponding sources were modified.

You do not need to edit contents of `out` folder.

Comment: Does it help to run "Build" before execution?

Comment: ah sorry for wasting your time, i think the build B4 run thing worked, and i just got that i shouldnt learn java first, but C